# How to get Unique List of Objects which has highest event date in the field event_date in the Iterable<Student> collection

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Iterable<Student> studentList` which contains student objects with fields id,event_date and many more.

```
Iterable<Student> myStudentList (contains student objects);
```

Now this studentlist contains many objects for one student id . 
lets say i need to modify this studentlist such that it contains only few student objects (one per one student id and that student object should contain maximum event_date for all the student objects for its student_id ) . How do i do this efficiently?

For example. Currently the list contains below items

```
ListIndex  |  Student ID | Student Name | Student Event Date |
0            RV001         Mahesh          1328532774000
1            RV002         James           1328532774000
2            RV002         James           1454763174000
3            RV002         James           1549457671000
4            RV001         Mahesh          1549457671000
5            RV003         Andy            1454763174000
```

***Expected Result***

And now my result `Iterable<Student>` list should contain below as a result

```
ListIndex  |  Student ID | Student Name | Student Event Date |
0            RV001         Mahesh          1549457671000
1            RV002         James           1549457671000
2            RV003         Andy            1454763174000
```

How do i achieve this efficiently using java 8 ?

This data is coming from table which is partitioned by event_date

My approach currently which i can think of :-P

```
Step 1 - Create a HashMap<Student_id, List<Student>>
Step 2 - Create a final List<Student> finalList for result purpose.
Step 2 - Iterate through the List<Student> 
    (a) For each student_id , store the list of Student objects in the  
        Map
         -- END of Iterating List<Student>
Step 3 - Iterate Each Map Entry in HashMap 
        (a) For every key , Apply Comparator on List<Student> for 
         current student id.
        (b) Get the first object of List<Student> in map for current 
            student_id and add it to the final list
```

Let me know if you have better approaches.

Comment: find the highest event date and then filter students by date value

Comment: Where's your code and your data structures?

Comment: this looks like an attempt to convert a resultset coming from the database to an object structure, but done wrong. You should not have several 'James' in your list, but rather have one 'James' having multiple events, and eventually a method "findMostRecentEventDate()".

Comment: @spi - Yes you are right , but this is partitionedTable and i recieve the data as prescribed in the question .

Comment: What kind of object event_date is?

Comment: @AnastasiosMoraitis - event_date is of type object , but it can be casted to either Timestamp or Long

Answer (score 4):

You might just be looking for something like:

```
List<Student> finalList = students.stream()
        // group by Id, value as List
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getId, 
        // reduce the list of values to only one with greater event_date 
                Collectors.reducing((student, student2) -> 
                        student.getEvent_date() > student2.getEvent_date() ? student : student2)))
        .values() // stream only such values
        .stream()
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect to list
```

Or as Holger pointed out, you can use

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getId, Function.identity(), 
                  (s1, s2) -> s1.getEvent_date() > s2.getEvent_date() ? s1: s2))
```

this would need you to wrap the values of the map formed here within the `new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: I have considered `event_date` of `long` type.

Comment: Whenever your downstream collector encapsulates a reduction, forcing you to deal with an `Optional` result, consider using `toMap` instead of `groupingBy`: `collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getId, Function.identity(), (s1, s2) -> s1.getEvent_date() > s2.getEvent_date()? s1: s2))`.

Comment: @Holger noted, was wondering at some point over the `get` without the `isPresent` check.

Comment: Well, using Java 8’s builtin collectors only, you can assume that reducing the groups of `groupingBy` will never lead to an empty `Optional`, thus, you can skip the `isPresent` check in this isolated scenario. However, with custom collectors or Java 9’s `filtering` or `flatmapping` collectors, this assumption may not hold anymore. So reusing such code for different situations can be fragile.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @nullpointer answer, but assuming event date has `int`, `long` or `double` type, you can use `maxBy` downstream with `comparingInt`, `comparingLong` or `comparingDouble` comparator

```
studentList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Student::getId, 
             maxBy(Comparator.comparingLong(Student::getEventDate))))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Indeed `maxBy` internally does `reduce` only...equivalent to `reducing(BinaryOperator.maxBy(comparator))`